# Why doesn't my Ti-84 simplify fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

Say we have:

$$\frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14$$

When I calculate this on my TI-84 Plus CE-T, it gives

$$\frac {13}{12}$$

Instead of

$$1\frac {1}{12}$$

Is there any reason for it doing so and is this setting-related?

Comment: We should first ask you... **why** do you consider $\frac{13}{12}$ to be any less simplified than $1+\frac{1}{12}$.  It should be pointed out that compound fraction notation such as $1\frac{1}{12}$ is almost *never* used beyond elementary school and the preferred notation is the one the calculator gives.

Comment: In general: mixed numbers aren't useful for math; if you want to do anything with them, you'd generally have to convert them back to improper fractions anyways.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I'm new to mathematics. didn't know that notation was preferred.

Comment: Because mathematicians write fractions as $13/12$ while schoolchildren write then as $1\frac1{12}$.

Comment: No answer to this question should need to diminish the importance of mixed  numbers. Converting improper fraction into an integer plus a proper fraction is indeed very useful well beyond elementary school. The first thing anyone does when there is a Diophantine equation with a quotient is see if such reduction is possible. The first step done to integrate a rational function is nothing but the same procedure. It is just misleading an already confused student.

Comment: @Marja I will point out that I did not say the notation $1+\frac{1}{12}$ isn't used, certainly it is and has its uses as you point out... however in any of those instances where we *do* want it immediately visible what the integer part of the fraction is we will use a plus sign as opposed to omitting it like in $1\frac{1}{12}$.  [Here is a relevant question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390166/what-is-the-purpose-of-mixed-numbers-outside-of-common-usage) on the usage of mixed numbers in today's society and mathematics.

Comment: I don't think anyone has mentioned that there is an ambiguity problem with the mixed-number notation.  In almost all other contexts, juxtaposition means multiplication. Does $2\frac{1}{3}$ equal $\frac{2}{3}$ or $\frac{7}{3}$?

Answer (score 4):

It's just how it's built in. In fact, you can change the output to give mixed numbers (I don't remember where). But as mentioned in comments, in general, mixed numbers really aren't preferred in any field of mathematics, but may be useful for the layperson in another field.